# How to add an extra module for bridge on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, react-native, react-native-native-module, react-native-modules

I have created a new native module in my `React Native` application (It's called `RCTAVAudioSessionModule`).
When looking in the `AppDelegate` I found this code snippet:

```
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
    NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *extraModules = [_moduleRegistryAdapter extraModulesForBridge:bridge];
    // If you'd like to export some custom RCTBridgeModules that are not Expo modules, add them here!
    return extraModules;
}
```

I want to add my native module to the `extraModules` array.
I tried to do something like that:

```
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
    NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *extraModules = [_moduleRegistryAdapter extraModulesForBridge:bridge];
    // If you'd like to export some custom RCTBridgeModules that are not Expo modules, add them here!
    return [extraModules arrayByAddingObject:(RCTAVAudioSessionModule.new)];
}
```

However, when I try to call a method from module I get an error that says:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RCTAVAudioSessionModule.getCurrentRoute')
```

How can I correctly add my native module and use it on iOS?